# Is it best practice to specify all T-SQL in-args as READONLY?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Generally speaking, procedures don't modify input arguments in my experience, so it seems like it might be good practice to mark all input parameters `READONLY` apart from those you explicitly need to be non-read-only.

But I'm not a SQLServer guy, is there any acknowledged best practice here?

Comment: I believe only T-SQL TVP parameters may be declared as `READONLY`.

Comment: @DanGuzman I seem to be seeing this behaviour when I tried it but that's not what the documentation suggests should be the case. It says you _have_ to use it for TVPs. Maybe this question is therefore NULL

Comment: I agree.  Looks like a doc issue.

Comment: Hmm, are best practices "primarily opinion based"? That seems rather to make having therm a bit pointless if you can just say "oh that's just your opinion". I'm not asking which way is right, I am asking _if_ there _is_ a best practice that applies.

Answer (score 1):

Table valued parameters must be readonly in sql server.
From the relevant [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx) page:

> **Restrictions**
> Table-valued parameters have the following restrictions:

> - SQL Server does not maintain statistics on columns of table-valued parameters.
> - Table-valued parameters must be passed as input READONLY parameters to Transact-SQL routines. You cannot perform DML operations such as UPDATE, DELETE, or INSERT on a table-valued parameter in the body of a routine.
> - You cannot use a table-valued parameter as target of a SELECT INTO or INSERT EXEC statement. A table-valued parameter can be in the FROM clause of SELECT INTO or in the INSERT EXEC string or stored procedure.

However, other types of variables may or may not be readonly, and it's the developer's responsibility to decide whether to mark them as readonly or not.
A stored procedure's input parameter can't be used outside the stored procedure's body, so it really doesn't matter if it's readonly or not.

I personally never bother to indicate readonly on parameters that are not table types, and often will use input parameters inside the stored procedure as if they where locally-declared variables. I find it easier to write, read, and maintain compact code, so if I have a parameter that can be used to set values inside the procedure and it's name makes sense both as a parameter and as a variable, I'm gladly setting values to in inside the procedure.

While you are on the subject of best practices, you might want to read [this article](https://sqlblog.org/2008/10/30/my-stored-procedure-best-practices-checklist) by Aaron Bertrand